# jQuery delay modification

Tags: jquery, delay

I am struggling to modify this part of code. Used setTimeout and .delay(). What this code does it answers user inputted question. It does it immediately and I'd like to make it look more natural and add human like answer delay.

```
 // Form submission - This is where the magic happens!
    $('#talkform').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var bot_name = $('#sbBot_id option:selected').text();
      var user = $('#say').val();
      var userSaid = userTitle + 'User: ' + endSpan + user + "<br>\n";
      $('#chatlog').html($('#chatlog').html() + userSaid);
      var botSaid = botTitle + "Admin: " + endSpan;
      var formdata = $("#talkform").serialize();
      $('#say').val('')
      $('#say').focus();
      $.post('<?php echo $url ?>', formdata, function(data){
        var b = data.botsay;
        if (b.indexOf('[img]') >= 0) {
          b = showImg(b);
        }
        if (b.indexOf('[link') >= 0) {
          b = makeLink(b);
        }
        var usersay = data.usersay;

        $('#chatlog').html($('#chatlog').html() + botSaid + b + "<br>\n");
      }, 'json').fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $('#urlwarning').html("Something went wrong! Error = " + errorThrown);
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: So... why not use setTimeout?

Comment: Okay I was putting setTimeout in wrong place... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Go through delay()'s entire documentation and you can specify time in seconds to gave it a more human like feel.

ex: `$( "#foo" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay( 4000 )         \\4 seconds delay
                               .fadeIn( 400 );`       \4 millisecs delay

Answer (score 0):

Put the string "$('#chatlog').html(..." into setTimeout handler function like in the following sample (2000 means 2s delay):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e){
      $("#submitbtn").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          
          // the code to receive answer
        
          setTimeout(function(){
              $("#answer").html("The answer is here");
          }, 2000);
      });
  });
```

```css
.asnwer {
    padding: 4px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=asnwer id=answer>&nbsp;</div>
<input id=submitbtn type=button value=submit>
```